# How do I add images to products in list view?

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, listview

I don't know how to add images to listview.

I tried adding

```
<asp:Image ID="image" runat="server" Width ="150" Hight="150" 
    ImageUrl=<%# Eval("pimg") %> />

<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource">
    <AlternatingItemTemplate>
        <span style="">
            name:
            <asp:Label ID="pnameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("pname") %>' />
            <br />
            price:
            <asp:Label ID="ppriceLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("pprice") %>' />
            <br /><br />
        </span>
    </AlternatingItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <span style="">
            name:
            <asp:TextBox ID="pnameTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("pname") %>' />
            <br />
            price:
            <asp:TextBox ID="ppriceTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("pprice") %>' />
            <br />
            <asp:Button ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" CommandName="Update" Text="Update" />
            <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
            <br /><br />
        </span>
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <EmptyDataTemplate>
        <span>No data was returned.</span>
    </EmptyDataTemplate>
    <InsertItemTemplate>
        <span style="">
            name:
            <asp:TextBox ID="pnameTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("pname") %>' />
            <br />
            price:
            <asp:TextBox ID="ppriceTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("pprice") %>' />
            <br />
            <asp:Button ID="InsertButton" runat="server" CommandName="Insert" Text="Insert" />
            <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Clear" />
            <br /><br />
        </span>
    </InsertItemTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <span style="">
            name:
            <asp:Label ID="pnameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("pname") %>' />
            <br />
            price:
            <asp:Label ID="ppriceLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("pprice") %>' />
            <br /><br />
        </span>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <div id="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" style="">
            <span runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder" />
        </div>
        <div style="">
        </div>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <SelectedItemTemplate>
       <span style="">
            name:
            <asp:Label ID="pnameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("pname") %>' />
            <br />
            price:
            <asp:Label ID="ppriceLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("pprice") %>' />
            <br /><br />
        </span>
    </SelectedItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

I didn't add images to the DataBase but I added their URLs and put all the images in a folder called img.
The header of the image urls in access is pimg.
How do I add the images to the ListView?

Answer (score 0):

The image-url needs single-quotes around it. Check out all the other `Eval`s and `Bind`s to see other examples.

```
ImageUrl='<%# Eval("pimg") %>'
```